How to Optimize Large CSV Processing?
TL;DR: I’m processing a large CSV (4M rows, 510 columns) but only need a few thousand rows with all columns at the end. The whole process takes 70+ minutes and uses a lot of memory. Looking for ways to optimize the workflow using Pandas.

I’m dealing with some performance and memory issues while processing a large CSV dataset. The entire process, from reading the dataset to saving the final CSV, is very time and memory intensive. While I can just about manage to run it on my local machine, I’m struggling to make it work on QA server. I'm hoping to get some advice on how to optimize this workflow.

I have a dataset with 4 million rows and 510 columns. However, I only need about 10 columns for most of the processing steps. At the very end of the process, I need to have all 510 columns available for writing the final CSV output.

Reading this dataset using Pandas takes around 20 minutes. I’ve managed to bring it down to 15 minutes by reading the data in chunks, but that’s still a long time.

After reading, I perform deduplication based on a composite key, which reduces the dataset from 4 million rows to about 1.3 million rows. This deduplication step alone takes another 20 minutes.

Once deduplication is done, I left join the dataset (1.3 million rows) with another smaller dataset that has around 3000 records. Since the join is based on the smaller dataset, I only need around 2950 rows from the larger dataset in the final result.

After the join, I do some basic formatting and save the result as a CSV. The final output contains all 700 columns (including columns from both datasets) but only about 3000 rows.


What I Need Help With:

Is there a way to reduce the time it takes to read this large dataset (currently around 15-20 minutes)?
Since I only need about 3000 rows in the final output but process 1.3 million rows during the pipeline, is there a way to minimize memory usage by loading only the necessary data early in the process and fetching the remaining columns later?
Are there any best practices or techniques in Pandas for handling large CSV files efficiently, especially when most columns aren’t needed until the final step?
Any suggestions on how to improve memory efficiency and performance would be much appreciated, especially if they stick to Pandas or similar libraries (since libraries like Dask are not available in our environment).


4 million rows in a CSV file suggests (to me) a fundamental design problem.

As above, I'd start by converting the CSV into a less inefficient format (preferably one that won't involve parsing of 2 billion values from plain text every time you want to do something with it).

Can you use Python’s standard csv module? I was thinking of a program with the csv module that could do this, and I’d expect it’d only take a few minutes (processor and disk-speed dependent, of course) to do everything you mentioned.

1. I’d use usecols Parameter when Reading the CSV
Since you only need about 10 columns in last, I’d suggest, load only those columns initially. You can later load the remaining columns when you need to write the final output.
cols_needed = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] 
df = pd.read_csv('large_file.csv', usecols=cols_needed, chunksize=100000)

2. Using Right Join
When joining with the smaller dataset (3000 records), it might help to keep the larger dataset in chunks and join each chunk with the smaller dataset using right join, So that only those records will be kept which are found in the smaller one.
small_df = pd.read_csv('small_dataset.csv')  
 
final_chunks = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('large_file.csv', usecols=cols_needed, chunksize=100000):
    joined_chunk = pd.merge(chunk, small_df, on='join_key', how='right')
    final_chunks.append(joined_chunk)
 
final_df = pd.concat(final_chunks, ignore_index=True)

Hope this helps.

Dedupe
A simple but very efficient dedupe uses a dict to store previously seen values and quickly look them up to determine if a row is a duplicate.
If we started with a small, sample of rows of names and ages:
data = [
    ["Bobby",    "24"],
    ["Alice",    "34"],
    ["Charlie",  "19"],
    ["Bobby",    "25"],
]

Deduping could like:

Create the "seen" dict, which maps a string (of seen keys) to None.
For every row, use the first field (name) as the key used to match other duplicate rows.
Look for the key in the dict, and if key is not found print the row and add the key to the dict for subsequent rows to check against. Otherwise do nothing, essentially "dropping" the row.

seen: dict[str, None] = {}

for row in data:
    _key = row[0]
    if _key not in seen:
        print(row)
        seen[_key] = None

print("Seen (name):")
print(seen)

Running that prints:
["Bobby",   "24"]
["Alice",   "34"]
["Charlie", "19"]

Seen (name):
{
    "Bobby":   None,
    "Alice":   None,
    "Charlie": None,
}

The row [Bobby, 25] was dropped because Bobby was alread in the dict when that row was processed. If you wanted to use the age as part of the dupe key, you could modify the key to use both fields:
key = row[0] + "_" + row[1]

and that would print:
['Bobby',   '24']
['Alice',   '34']
['Charlie', '19']
['Bobby',   '25']

Seen (name_age):
{
    "Bobby_24":   None,
    "Alice_34":   None,
    "Charlie_19": None,
    "Bobby_25":   None,
}

I added the underscore between the two values to make reading the key easier while debugging.
Join
Joining two datasets uses a dict again.
We start by reading the smaller dataset first (I'll call the "reference" list), and this time associate the whole row with the key. We can also extract the making of the key into its own function since we will need the key in two different places in the program, and it'll be easier to maintain if we define it once and use it multiple times:
def get_key(row: list[str]) -> str:
    return row[0]

ref_data = [
    ["Bobby", "24", "green"],
    ["Alice", "34", "red"],
]

ref_rows: dict[str, list[str]] = {}

for row in ref_data:
    _key = get_key(row)
    ref_rows[_key] = row

print(ref_rows)

Which prints:
Ref rows:
{
    'Bobby_24': ['Bobby', '24', 'green'],
    'Alice_34': ['Alice', '34', 'red'],
}

Then, read the (name-only) deduped data and print only the joined rows:
deduped_data = [
    ["Bobby", "24"],
    ["Alice", "34"],
    ["Charlie", "19"],
]

for row in deduped_data:
    _key = get_key(row)
    if _key in ref_rows:
        ref_row = ref_rows[_key]
        print(ref_row + row)

That prints:
['Bobby', '24', 'green', 'Bobby', '24']
['Alice', '34', 'red', 'Alice', '34']

Putting it together

Dedupe the 4M rows down to ~1.3M rows
Join the 1.3M rows with ~3K reference rows to yield ~3K rows

import csv

INPUT_BIG_CSV = "00-input-big.csv"  # ~4M rows
INPUT_REF_CSV = "01-input-ref.csv"  # ~3K rows
DEDUPED_CSV   = "05-deduped.csv"    # output of dedupe
JOINED_CSV    = "10-joined.csv"     # output of join; final


def dedupe():
    seen: dict[str, None] = {}

    with (
        open(INPUT_BIG_CSV,      newline="") as f_in,
        open(DEDUPED_CSV,   "w", newline="") as f_out,
    ):
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        writer = csv.writer(f_out)

        writer.writerow(next(reader))     # copy header

        for row in reader:
            _key = row[0] + "_" + row[1]  # + "_" ...
            if _key not in seen:
                writer.writerow(row)
                seen[_key] = None


def join():
    # record the headers and append them for the final header
    ref_header: list[str]     = []
    deduped_header: list[str] = []


    def get_key(row: list[str]) -> str:
        return row[2] + "_" + row[3]  # + "_" ...

    # -- Read reference list and store rows

    ref_rows: dict[str, list[str]] = {}

     with open(INPUT_REF_CSV, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        ref_header = next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            _key = get_key(row)
            ref_rows[_key] = row

    # -- Read deduped list and join with ref rows

    with (
        open(INPUT_BIG_CSV,      newline="") as f_in,
        open(JOINED_CSV,    "w", newline="") as f_out,
    ):
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        writer = csv.writer(f_out)

        deduped_header = next(reader)
        writer.writerow(ref_header + deduped_header)

        for row in reader:
            _key = get_key(row)
            if _key in ref_rows:
                ref_row = ref_rows[_key]
                writer.writerow(ref_row + row)

I created some test CSVs: big was 400K rows by 50 cols (210MB); reference was 3000 rows by 5 cols (88KB). Running both dedupe and join took about 2.5s and 0.6s (respectively) on my machine:

the test big CSV was about 1/100th the size by rows and cols compared to yours, so I'd expect it to take at least 100 times longer to run: 250s. It was engineered to dedupe from 400K rows to 135K rows.
the test ref CSV was about 1/40th the size compared to yours (if I read the post correctly) but it's so small the size difference with yours will be pretty negligible. The real performance difference will come from reading 1.3M rows vs my 130K deduped test rows.

Really, those estimates will probably scale with the size of the files in bytes (concrete performance factor) and not the "dimensions" of the tables (material, but less concrete factor), but I don't know how big in bytes your files are for the dimensions you stated, so I'll just roughly estimate based on dimensions.
